# Using python argparse for custom modules comand line arguments

Tags: python, module, argparse

I'm building a set of scripts and modules for some project.  By request, there are some required command line arguments.  Also some modules can use some custom arguments (like numerical tolerance, or parameters).  All the scripts and modules can use another set of common arguments (verbosity level, for example).

I'm trying to use the python3 argparse for that.

```
|- bin
|   +- scriptN.py
|- lib
|   +- requested_args.py
|   +- common_args.py
|   +- dataset.py
|   +- modelN.py
```

I tried to use a nested parent argparser, as:

in scriptN.py:

```
 parser = argparser.ArgumentParser(parents=[requested_args.parser,
                                            commont_args.parser,
                                            dataset.parser,
                                            modelN.parser]
```

And for the `modelN` file:

```
parser = argparser.ArgumentParser(add_help=False,
                                  parents=[requested_args.parser,
                                           commont_args.parser]
```

So `request_args` and `common_args` parsers are "included" twice, resulting that the same option is already defined.

I need to expose in `scriptN.py` all the options for the imported modules, and each module can access their own args, and the two common modules.  For simplicity, each module/script has a "`args`" object.

I tried to use the approach described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494574/using-pythons-argparse-in-multiple-scripts-backed-by-multiple-custom-modules), but I can`t figure how to expose the module args within the module.  How can I join all argparses, and maintain all the parsedArguments available in each module and for all modules?

Thanks

Comment: The `parents` mechanism simply copies argument (`Action` object) references from the parent to the child.  It doesn't actually run the parent parser.   `conflict_handler='resolve'` is another way of handling repeated Action definitions, but it isn't robust.  You may need to customize this `handler`, or write your own variation on the `parents` mechanism.

Comment: `add_argument` creates an `argparse.Action` subclass object, and stores references to it in several places, including the `parser_actions` list.  But look at `parser._add_container_actions` to see how Actions are actually copied from one parser to another.  It isn't trivial.

Comment: @hpaulj: For the conflict problem, I can also remove all `parents` in `dataset` and `modelN` files.  Only keep on `scriptN`. I really want to make the parsed arguments available inside the module.

Comment: It there aren't required arguments, and with `parse_known_args` it is possible to use several parsers at once, each handling only the arguments it knows about.  A different approach is to have one master parser, and have it pass its `args` variable to the sub modules.  That's an inter-module variable issue, not an `argparse` one.